Multiply elements of list column in polars dataframe with elements of regular python list
I have a pl.DataFrame with a column comprising lists like this:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "roc": [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8]],
    }
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌────────┬────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  │
╞════════╪════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] │
└────────┴────────────┘

Further, I have a regular python list weights = [0.3, 0.7]
What's an efficient way to multiply pl.col("roc") with weights in a way where the first and second element of the column will be multiplied with the first and second element of weights, respectively?
The expected output is like this:
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┐──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        │ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  │ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╡══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] │ [0.03, 0.14] │ = [0.1 * 0.3, 0.2 * 0.7]
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] │ [0.09, 0.28] │ = [0.3 * 0.3, 0.4 * 0.7]
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] │ [0.15, 0.42] │ = [0.5 * 0.3, 0.6 * 0.7]
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] │ [0.21, 0.56] │ = [0.7 * 0.3, 0.8 * 0.7]
└────────┴────────────┘──────────────┘


Update: Broadcasting of literals/scalars for the List type was added in 1.10.0
df.with_columns(roc_wgt = pl.col.roc * weights)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘


As of Polars 1.8.0 list arithmetic has been merged.
Follow on work will add support for broadcasting of literals (and scalars).

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8006

It can be added as a column for now.
(df.with_columns(wgt = weights)
   .with_columns(roc_wgt = pl.col.roc * pl.col.wgt)
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ wgt        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.3, 0.7] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.3, 0.7] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.3, 0.7] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.3, 0.7] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘

Broadcasting of literals works for the Array datatype as of 1.8.0
dtype = pl.Array(float, 2)

df.with_columns(roc_wgt = pl.col.roc.cast(dtype) * pl.lit(weights, dtype))

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬───────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt       │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---           │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ array[f64, 2] │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14]  │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28]  │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42]  │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56]  │
└────────┴────────────┴───────────────┘


That's a pretty consice solution. What if I were to compute the sumproduct of pl.col("roc") and pl.col("wgt")? Is it simply something like pl.col("roc_wgt").arr.sum()?

You can also do df.with_columns(     roc_wgt = pl.col('roc').list.eval(pl.element()*pl.Series(weights)) )

One option by first running explode:
(df.with_row_index().with_columns(l=weights).explode(['roc', 'l'])
   .with_columns(roc_wgt=pl.col('roc')*pl.col('l'))
   .group_by('index')
   .agg(pl.col('symbol').first(),
        pl.col('roc'),
        pl.col('roc_wgt'))
)

Output:
┌───────┬────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ index ┆ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ 1     ┆ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ 2     ┆ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ 3     ┆ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└───────┴────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘

Alternatively, with map_elements:
import numpy as np

df.with_columns(roc_wgt=pl.col('roc')
                          .map_elements(lambda x: x*np.array(weights),
                                        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64)))

Output:
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘


You can also iterate over your weights list, grab the corresponding element
from your column, multiply them together and concatenate those results together
in a new list.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "roc": [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8]],
    }
)

weights = [.3, .7]

print(
    df.with_columns(
        roc_wgt=pl.concat_list(
            pl.col('roc').list.get(i) * wgt for i, wgt in enumerate(weights)
        )
    )
)
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
# │ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
# │ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
# │ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
# ╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
# │ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
# │ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
# │ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
# │ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
# └────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘


updated.
Since version 1.10.0 arithmetic operations between lists and scalars are supported:
df.with_columns(roc_wgt = weights * pl.col.roc)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘

outdated*. With latest release of version 1.8.0 arithmetic operations on list are also supported:
(
    df
    .with_columns(roc_wgt = pl.lit(weights))
    .with_columns(pl.col.roc_wgt * pl.col.roc)
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘

outdated. Unfortunately, polars doesn't support such operations with lists yet, but it does support them with structs:
(
    df.with_columns(
        roc_wgt = pl.col.roc.list.to_struct() * pl.lit(weights).list.to_struct()
    ).with_columns(
        roc_wgt = pl.concat_list(pl.col.roc_wgt.struct.field("*"))
    )
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ roc        ┆ roc_wgt      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0.1, 0.2] ┆ [0.03, 0.14] │
│ A      ┆ [0.3, 0.4] ┆ [0.09, 0.28] │
│ B      ┆ [0.5, 0.6] ┆ [0.15, 0.42] │
│ B      ┆ [0.7, 0.8] ┆ [0.21, 0.56] │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘

